# How can i redirect smtp port 25 to port 465

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010, redirect, smtps

I have Exchnage server ,I can receive emails But I can not send emails out of the domain because Port 25 is block in ISP

How can i redirect smtp port 25 to SMTPS port 465 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mail hop service if port 25 is blocked by your ISP. This could also be a third party spam filtering service that is able to deliver email to another port. The rest of the internet uses port 25, they cannot make an exception for you.